# Python plt.show shows a blank figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to figure out why an extra blank figure is shown using this code, there should be only two figures but three are shown where one is empty. Here is an image showing what happens:

[image: Figures]

Here is the code I am using:

```
f1 = plt.figure(1)
img=mpimg.imread(image_path)
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)

original_image = Image.open(image_path)
bw_image = original_image.convert('1', dither=Image.NONE)

bw_image_array = np.array(bw_image, dtype=np.int)
black_indices = np.argwhere(bw_image_array == 0)
chosen_black_indices = black_indices[np.random.choice(black_indices.shape[0], replace=False, size=3000)]

distances = pdist(chosen_black_indices) 
distance_matrix = squareform(distances)

optimized_path = solve_tsp(distance_matrix)

optimized_path_points = [chosen_black_indices[x] for x in optimized_path]
f2 = plt.figure(2)
plt.xlim(0, 600)  
plt.ylim(0, 800)  
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()  
plt.xticks([])  
plt.yticks([])
xstartdata = optimized_path_points[0][0]
ystartdata = optimized_path_points[0][1]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ln, = plt.plot([], [], color='black', marker='o', linestyle='dashed', markersize=1, animated=True)
plt.plot([xstartdata], [ystartdata], color='black', marker='o', linestyle='dashed', markersize=1,  lw=0.1)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
x = []
y = []

def init():
    ln.set_data([],[])

    return ln,

def animate(i):
    x.append(optimized_path_points[i][1])
    y.append(optimized_path_points[i][0])

    ln.set_data(x, y)
    plt.plot(x , y , lw=0.1,animated=True)
    return ln,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,frames=range(len(optimized_path_points)), interval=5, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I'd suggest switching to the object-oriented API (`ax.plot` etc) for full control. Short answer is probably that `plt.subplots` also opens a figure.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: I'd use explicit `fig,ax = plt.subplots` calls and then only use `ax` methods for plotting.